# Orbeon form builder: Using date fields with initial value "current-date()"

Tags: orbeon, xforms

I am using date fields in Orbeon form builder that should be prefilled with the current date (see http://i42.tinypic.com/erdjrb.jpg). When choosing a date by hand in the form, the date format in resulting XML model is set to "2011-07-12". But when not changing the default value of current-date(), then I get "2011-07-12+02:00". Does anybody know why the date format is different when I prefill it with current-date()?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The XPath function [`fn:current-date()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-current-date) by definition returns the date together with explicit time zone information. I assume orbeon just passes the function call to the XPath engine (Saxon i think). A quick workaround would be to format the result of `current-date()` using `format-date()`, for example:

```
format-date(current-date(), '[Y]-[M01]-[D01]')
```

Since i don't use Form Builder, i can't tell in detail, but i assume [setting the config options how to format xforms:input controls regarding date and time values](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/configuration-properties/configuration-properties-xforms#TOC-For-xforms%3ainput-) applies for form builder, too.

Comment: You can also use `adjust-date-to-timezone()` with an empty sequence as the second argument. Quoting from the spec: "If $timezone is the empty sequence, returns an xs:date without a timezone." So you can write: `adjust-date-to-timezone(current-date(), ())`. http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-adjust-date-to-timezone

Comment: @avernet: you're right, using `adjust-date-to-timezone()` is even better because it preserves the `xs:date` type, while `format-date()` returns a `xs:string`.